# Op-amp with Schottky diode

Tags: operational-amplifier, diodes, schmitt-trigger, schottky, diode-clamp

I'm struggling to understand what the sense is of using the two Schottky diodes in this excerpt of a circuit:

[image]

I understand how a Schmitt trigger works. The diodes ensure that the voltage difference between the two inputs can't pass the diodes forward voltage. But can the Schmitt trigger even to operate then?

My idea of this circuit is that the voltage difference between the two inputs is constant, e.g. 0.4 V, independent of the input voltages, so how can the op-amp operate?

Comment: What are I1 and I2 - currents, voltages or inputs?

Comment: I for input voltage, sorry in my intuition that was clear :)

Comment: I had never seen voltage denoted by the letter "I" before, so I asked. I think this circuit is a misunderstanding because the three resistors are always connected through one of the diodes, and this changes the switching thresholds beyond recognition. I don't think it deserves that kind of attention. Diodes make sense in a negative feedback circuit where there is a virtual short between the inputs. There they do not affect the circuit operation.

Comment: Although, I keep thinking, there is a point of view that needs to be checked - to consider the input sources connected via the circuit of the two 22 k resistors in series (*voltage divider* or, more precisely said, *resistor summer*)... I'll think about it albeit reluctantly…

Answer (score 6):

The diodes conduct hardly at all near the switching point, which is where the two input voltages are almost equal (within a mV or so for most op-amps), so they can be ignored when analyzing the circuit to find the switching point. See this curve from a [datasheet](https://4donline.ihs.com/images/VipMasterIC/IC/VISH/VISH-S-A0003301798/VISH-S-A0004270193-1.pdf).

[image]

The Schottky diodes keep the differential voltage from getting too large when the voltage difference between the two inputs would otherwise be relatively large, which may have other benefits.

For example, if I1 is +10V and I2 is -10V there will be about 450uA flowing (ignoring the positive feedback resistor), so the differential input voltage at the op-amp will be only about 250mV at 25°C rather than more like 20V.

Comment: Ok, I guess my problem resides from the fact that I‘m not sure how to calculate the voltage here for example at the non-inverting input as there are 3 voltages to be taken into account. Is it right to calculate the voltage two times by applying superposition and then to add these voltages?

Comment: You can use superposition if the assumption the diodes are not conducting is true, otherwise you can't use superposition because it's no longer a linear circuit. But the voltages don't matter to the function unless the diodes are not conducting. In that case, only one or two voltages matter since there is no interaction through the diodes. If they are conducting you can use the 0.25V or so forward voltage, but under those conditions you will know the output state of the op-amp- it will be railed one side or the other, depending on the polarity. Is that clear enough?

Comment: Ok, thanks. but I'm actually searching for a mathematical way to describe the voltage for example in the non-inverting input. There's still a Schmitt trigger in the circuit. Let I2=0V and the output of the OpAmp is 10 V. In what way does I1 now influence the potential at the non-inverting input to switch the state of the OpAmp? In my opinion I1 has to decrease but how much? I imagine a state where I1 is negative but no enough as the Opamp still outputs its 10V and it that case I want to predict what the potential at the non-inverting inputs really is?

Comment: Okay, it will only switch when the inputs are equal, so ignore the diodes. I2 is 0V so the inverting input is 0V and therefore the non-inverting input must be 0V at the switching  point. So we have a simple voltage divider. Non-inverting input is at 0V and output is at 10V  so we know 10V/750kΩ = 13.3uA is flowing through the divider. I2 thus must be at -22kΩ x 13.3uA = -293mV. If the output was at +10V the answer would be +293mV, so the total hysteresis would be about 600mV.

Answer (score 4):

> *My idea of this circuit is that the voltage is difference between the
> two inputs is constant e.g. 0.4 V, independent of the input voltages,
> so how can the op-amp operate?*

Your understanding is flawed. The diodes clamp the voltage between the two inputs to around 0.4 volts maximum i.e. they don't impose a voltage that's 0.4 volts except if the external inputs and feedback generate a voltage higher than 0.4 volts.

Answer (score 3):

> ... the voltage is difference between the two inputs is constant e.g. 0.4 V, independent of the input voltages, ...

Diodes are 1N4148. This is not true.

Here are two examples of simulating with opamp. R1 reduced to 100 kOhm.
Same behavior. Not the same V4.

This is complicated if R1 is equal to 750 kOhm.

This first works with LF13741, powered with +/- 15 V.

[image]

This other works with a TL082C powered with +/- 5 V.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## Building Schmitt trigger

Here is a possible scenario for building the circuit in four steps that might help make sense of it.

### 1.Producing V- and V+

First we connect the two input stage sources through 22 kΩ resistors to nodes (-) and (+) indicated by voltmeters. As we can see, the voltmeters read the same voltages because no currents flow through the resistors.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0q0zj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

### 2.Adding op-amp

Then we connect an op-amp to compare the input voltages. Since the two voltages are the same, the op-amp output voltage is 0 V, but that is only possible here in the simulator environment. In the practical circuit, the output voltage will stay close to one of the supply rails because of the voltage offset and the extremely high op-amp gain.

You can first play around with manually setting V2 values ​​to toggle the comparator...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNAcKh.png)</sup>

... and then see how the comparator switches on increasing and decreasing (triangle) voltage V2 (run *Time-Domain Simulation*).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fx2uyB.png)</sup>

We see that regardless of the direction, the comparator switches at the same voltage level (5 V).

[image: STEP 2.2]

### 3.Introducing hysteresis

The problem is that small fluctuations of the input voltages can cause the comparator to oscillate at the time of switching. We can solve this problem by introducing the so-called "hysteresis". This simply means to help the input source V2 by lowering the threshold at the time of switching. Thus, when V2 changes in the opposite direction, the comparator will switch later. So, hysteresis means that the comparator has a *dynamic threshold* or two thresholds.

But how do we do it? We can make the op-amp itself "help" V2 by adding some voltage to it. To do this, we simply connect a resistor R3 between the output and the non-inverting input that together with R2 forms a *resistor summer*. The name of this trick is *positive feedback*.

Try switching the comparator manually first...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fC5fQ7.png)</sup>

... and then with a triangular signal in time (run *Time-Domain Simulation*).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fv8IhC.png)</sup>

As you can see, the circuit now has two thresholds.

[image: STEP 3.1]

### 4.Adding protecting diodes

We have come to the heart of the matter - the two back-to-back diodes. For some reason they are Schottky diodes. I suspect not because of the lower voltage, but because of the higher speed... but whatever. We can represent them by "ideal" diodes with a forward voltage of 400 mV from the CircuitLab library. Our task is to find out if they somehow change the circuit operation.

If we compare Schematic 3.1 (without diodes) and 4.1 below (with diodes), we will see that there is a difference only in the end states where the op-amp output voltage is either 10 V or -10 V. Only then one of the diodes connects as with some kind of "bridge" the two parts of the circuit controlled by V1 and V2.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDESpj.png)</sup>

The three resistors form a summer so that three voltages are added to the non-inverting input - V1 (via R1 and diode in series), V2 (via R2) and Vout (via R3).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXRoB0.png)</sup>

But in the brief moment when the voltages of the two op-amp inputs equalize, both diode are off, and there is no connection between the two nodes. That is why, the thresholds in the graph below are the same as in the graph of the Schematic 3.1.

[image: STEP 4.2]

## Conclusion

The protecting diodes do not change the thresholds of the Schmitt trigger.

Comment: The circuit seems to be working.  The difference with the circuit without diodes is the addition of one more term to the weighted sum (the superposition expression) which only complicates it. Thus the summing circuit has three weighted inputs.